when tries to Enable github pages by selcting source as main branch and root folder nothing is happening i dont know whats wrong i am doing (HTML)
I am trying to deploy a static HTML website using GitHub Pages. I have an index.html file in the root directory of my repository. Here's what I have done so far:
Created a public repository on GitHub and added my index.html file to the root directory.
Followed the GitHub Pages documentation to enable GitHub Pages.
Went to Settings > Pages, selected the main branch as the source, and chose / (root) as the folder.
Clicked "Save" to publish the site.
The Problem:
After clicking "Save," nothing happens. I don’t see the green banner with the GitHub Pages URL, and the site doesn’t appear to deploy. I’ve tried this with multiple repositories and the same issue occurs.
What I Have Already Tried:
Confirmed that the index.html file is in the root directory of the repository.
Verified that the repository is public.
Repeatedly tried setting the source branch to "None" and back to "main" to force a rebuild.
Tested on different repositories and browsers.
Cleared cache and cookies to ensure it’s not a client-side issue.
Additional Information:
There are no logs or workflows in the Actions tab for the Pages deployment.
The repository has no custom configurations—it's just a simple static site.
My Question:
How can I resolve this issue and successfully deploy my static HTML site using GitHub Pages? Is there something I am missing or a potential bug with GitHub Pages?
Thanks in advance for your help!
